# Having trouble adding event listeners to dynamic html inserted into LWC

Tags: lighting-web-component

I am trying to create some dynamic navigation to a LWC in a screen flow by adding onclick javascript that will set a field in the flow and trigger the NEXT event so that a decision element can redirect the user. The context is a long survey delivered by screen flow - at the end, the user can review questions, with any missing required information highlighted.

I am creating the HTML in my Apex (in part so I can re-use it in other contexts) and inserting it into the LWC. All onclick actions that I've tried to insert get stripped out, whether as onclick = in a link or a button, or in the href itself. Fair enough, from a clickjack perspective I guess. But nothing I have tried using getElementsByClassName() or this.template.querySelector() has found any elements to attach an event listener to.

I'd appreciate your guidance.

EngagementReportSummary.js

```
import { LightningElement,wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import {FlowAttributeChangeEvent, FlowNavigationNextEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';

import getSummary from '@salesforce/apex/EngagementReportDisplayController.ReportSummary';

export default class EngagementReportSummary extends LightningElement {
    @api ERid;
    @api firstRequired;
    //@track reportSummary;
    
    @wire(getSummary, {EngagementReportId: "$ERid"})
    getResults(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.reportSummary = result.data;
            const container = this.template.querySelector('.container');
            container.innerHTML = this.reportSummary;
        } else {
            console.log('Error', result.error);
        }
            
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        const container = this.template.querySelector('.container');
        
        console.log('rendered callback');
        
        /*
        function goToQuestion(fieldName){
            this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('firstRequired', this.fieldName));
            const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
            this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
        }*/

        
        var qid_ele = this.template.querySelector('.questionText');
        console.log(qid_ele.length + ' elements');
       
        for (var i = 0; i < qid_ele.length; ++i) {
            console.log(qid_ele[i].id);
            qid_ele[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                var fieldName = this.id.substring(7);
                this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('firstRequired',fieldName));
                alert(fieldName);
            });
            
        }
    
      }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
<div class="container" lwc:dom = "manual">
</div>
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class EngagementReportDisplayController {
    public EngagementReportDisplayController() {

    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get First Required Field' description='Return field name of first unfilled required response')
    public static list<string> nextRequired(list<string> EngagementReportId){
        list<string> requiredName = new list<string>();
        
        List<QandA> QAs = QuestionsAndAnswers(EngagementReportId[0]);

        
        for(QandA QA : QAs) {
            if(string.isblank(QA.Answertext) && QA.isRequired){
                requiredName.add(QA.fieldName);
                break;
            }
        }
        return requiredName;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string ReportSummary(string EngagementReportId){
        
        string output = '';

        List<QandA> QAs = QuestionsAndAnswers(EngagementReportId);
        //Iterate and create lines
        string lastQuestionLabel = '';
        boolean addClosingDiv = false; 
        integer responseCount = 1;
        
        for(QandA QA : QAs) {
            boolean newlabel = false;
                       
            string divclass = QA.isRequired ? 'required':'optional';
            divclass +='-';
            divclass += string.isblank(QA.Answertext) ? 'blank':'filled';
            string response = QA.AnswerText;
            
            if(QA.QuestionText != lastQuestionLabel){
                if(addClosingDiv){output += '</div>';}
                addClosingDiv = true;
                newlabel = true;
                string newLine = '<div class="'+divclass+' outerdiv-'+QA.fieldName+'" ><div class="questionText" id="header-'+QA.fieldName+'">'+QA.QuestionText;
                if(QA.isRequired){newLine += ' <span class="requiredLabel">Required</span>';}
                newLine += '</div>';
                output += newline;
                lastQuestionLabel = QA.QuestionText;
                responseCount = 1;
            }
            // for data line, if absent and unrequired, and not the first no need to show it. What to put for required/missing first line? 
            if(!string.isblank(QA.AnswerText) || responseCount == 1 || QA.isRequired){
                if(string.isblank(QA.AnswerText)){
                        response = 'No response';
                    }
                string newLine = '<div class="answer answer-'+divclass+' '+QA.fieldName+'"><span class="fieldLabel label-'+QA.fieldName+'">'+QA.label+': </span>'+response+'</div>';
                output += newline;   
            }
            
            responseCount ++;


        }

        output += '</div>';
        system.debug(output);
        return output;
        
    }

    public static list<QandA> QuestionsAndAnswers(string EngagementReportId){
        list<QandA> QuestionAndAnswerList = new list<QandA>();
        
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldset = getFields();   
        Engagement_Report__c EngagementReport = GetER(EngagementReportId);
        
        List<FieldDefinition> fieldDef = [Select Label, QualifiedApiName, DataType, Description from FieldDefinition Where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Engagement_Report__c'];

        map<string,FieldDefinition> fieldDefMap = new map<string,FieldDefinition>();

        for(FieldDefinition f: fieldDef){
            fieldDefMap.put(f.QualifiedApiName,f);
        }
        
        // list of fields that are to be skipped based on ER skip logic, hard coded here
        list<string> skipList = new list<string>();
        
        // list of fields that are to be required based on ER skip logic, hard coded here    
        list<string> reqList =  new list<string>();
        
        //skip DEI fields
        if(!(EngagementReport.get('Service_Line__c') == 'EQY' )
            && !(EngagementReport.get('Engagement_a_part_of_a_cohort__c') == 'Accelerating Equitable Outcomes')
            && !(EngagementReport.get('Engagement_a_part_of_a_cohort__c') == 'Racial Equity Leadership Academy (RELA)')){
                for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldSet){
                    if(f.getFieldPath().left(4)=='DEI_'){
                        skipList.add(f.getFieldPath());
                    }
                }
           }
        // skip Digital Economy Field
        if(!(EngagementReport.get('Engagement_a_part_of_a_cohort__c')=='Rural Resiliency')){
            skipList.add('Digital_Economy_Analyses_and_Changes__c');
        }
        
        if(EngagementReport.get('Engagement_type__c') == null){
            reqList.add('Inst_Goal_1__c');
            reqList.add('Inst_Goal_1_Progress_Rating__c');
            reqList.add('Capacity_1_Select__c');
            reqList.add('Capacity_1_Text__c');
            skiplist.add('Upload_Assessment_hyperlink__c');
            skiplist.add('Upload_ICAT_Report_hyperlink__c');
        } else {
            skiplist.add('Upload_President_s_Letter_hyperlink__c');
            skiplist.add('Upload_Agenda_hyperlink__c');
            
            list<string> Assessments = new List<String>{'Opportunity Assessment', 'Landscape Analysis', 'Policy Audit', 'Communication Audit'};
            
            string ETString = (string) EngagementReport.get('Engagement_type__c');
            if(!(Assessments.contains(ETString))){
                skiplist.add('Upload_Assessment_hyperlink__c');
            }
            if(!(ETString=='ICAT Assessment & Café')){
                skiplist.add('Upload_ICAT_Report_hyperlink__c');
            }
               
        }
            
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldSet) {
            if(!skipList.contains(f.getFieldPath())){
                QandA QA = new QandA(); 
                QA.fieldName = f.getFieldPath();
                QA.QuestionText = fieldDefMap.get(QA.fieldName).description;
                QA.IsRequired = f.getRequired() || reqList.contains(QA.fieldName);
                QA.label = fieldDefMap.get(QA.fieldName).Label;
                if(string.isblank(QA.QuestionText)){
                    QA.QuestionText =  QA.label;
                }
               
                string baseFieldType = fieldDefMap.get(QA.fieldName).DataType;
                
                if(EngagementReport.get(QA.fieldName)!= null){
                    if(baseFieldType.contains('Text')){
                        QA.AnswerText = (string) EngagementReport.get(QA.fieldName);
                    } else if (baseFieldType.contains('Multi-Select')) {
                        QA.AnswerText  = (string) EngagementReport.get(QA.fieldName);
                        if(!string.isblank(QA.AnswerText )){
                        list<string> multiSelectResponses = QA.AnswerText.split(';');
                        
                        QA.AnswerText  ='<ul>';
                        for(string s: multiSelectResponses){
                            if(!string.isblank(s.trim())){QA.AnswerText += '<li>'+ s +'</li>';}
                        }
                        QA.AnswerText  += '</ul>';
                        } else {
                            QA.AnswerText  = '';
                        }
                    } else if (baseFieldType.contains('Number') || baseFieldType.contains('Roll-Up Summary (SUM')) {
                        double numericResponse = (double) EngagementReport.get(QA.fieldName);
                        QA.AnswerText  = string.valueof(numericResponse);
                        
                    } else if (baseFieldType.contains('Date')) {
                        date dateResponse = (date) EngagementReport.get(QA.fieldName);
                        QA.AnswerText  = dateResponse.format();
                    } else {
                        QA.AnswerText  = (string) EngagementReport.get(QA.fieldName);
                    }
                    
                   
                } 
                QuestionAndAnswerList.add(QA);
            }

        }
        return QuestionAndAnswerList;
    }
    
    public static Engagement_Report__c GetER(string EngagementReportId){
        
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldset = getFields();            
        
        String query = 'SELECT ';

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldSet) {
                query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
            }
        query += 'Id FROM Engagement_Report__c where id = \''+EngagementReportId+'\'';
        
        Engagement_Report__c ER = database.query(query);
        
        Return ER;

    }
    

    public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.Engagement_Report__c.FieldSets.Validation_and_display.getFields();       
    }
    
    public class QandA {
        public string QuestionText;
        public string AnswerText;
        public boolean IsRequired;
        public string fieldName; 
        public string label;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't need to try messing with dynamic HTML to allow flow navigation on button click; ensure you provide an OUT API property in the LWC that can link to a variable in the flow to change where the flow goes next (in a decision element) - to do this you need to use a getter/setter pattern for the API property to let you write to it - and ensure you fire the `FlowAttributeChangeEvent` to have the flow pick up the change, then simply dispatch a `FlowNavigationNextEvent` too. The screen is followed by a decision that uses the variable, set by the LWC, to choose what to do next.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not where I'm stuck -- The HTML is displaying the questions and provided answers, and the intent is to allow the user to click on the question text and be taken (via the path you describe) to the corresponding screen of the flow. It's the onclick action that I can't figure out how to make happen.

Comment: Generate this using standard LWC functionality - there's no need for dynamic HTML.

Comment: In that case, what is the best way to pass the data to the LWC? (sorry, I'm pretty new to this - conversant in Apex but not in javascript) The data itself is basically a map class with a question as a header, and then one or more answers below it. A concern I had going in was that maps are unordered, and I need these to display in order. And like I said, I can reuse the HTML in related visualforce elements.

Comment: Instead of having your code generate dynamic HTML, make it generate the data that goes into that HTML, held in a (tracked) array property, then have a for loop over that property's data in the template, with the necessary bits of HTML in that template, using `{expressions}` to access the specific values to be inserted. The point is, your code is already doing the required ordering, so generate the array in the same way and "bob's your uncle"...

Comment: @PhilW it took me a little while to get my head around what you were suggesting, but it finally clicked and I'm making considerable progress.

Comment: I didn't have the time available to write a proper answer but wanted to point you in an alternative direction. Glad you appear to have managed to decode my scribblings.